# Django.model meta information

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a number of models which have hundreds of instances. Across those instances, there is information which is 'global' for all of them. As an example, I have a 'Sites' model which has many instances. I would like to have a 'meta-field' such as last_global_update which would have the last time all these sites were updated as a group.

So I have a classmethod 'update' which is called via Site.update(), and that updates all site instances with the latest information. Ideally there would then be a Site.last_global_update field which would give the datetime update() was last called.

Any idea how this could be achieved? I've tried a lot of different things using meta classes but nothing works - I can't have model fields dynamically updated and stored in metaclasses.

Comment: Why not use `inheritance`?

Comment: That would add a field to every instance. So to use the example I gave, every Site instance would then have a 'last_global_update' field, all with the same information. The problem with that is, some of the meta information I want to store would take up a sizable amount of room, so it shouldn't be duplicated hundreds of times. Also, to access it via inheritance I would have to get an instantiation of Site and access the field, rather than use the Site class itself.

Comment: You shouldn't make `last_global_update` instance variable but class variable. Than you are not replicating the object per instance, its going to be static for that class

Comment: You shouldn't make `last_global_update` instance variable but class variable. Than you are not replicating it per instance, its going to be static for that class.

Comment: I'm not sure how you distinguish between instance and class variables with django. Can you give a small code example?

Comment: It sounds like you almost want a <a href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/">generic relation</a>, except pointing to the model instead of any instance.

Comment: I second @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I would have two models linked via generic foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I ended up using:

```
class classproperty(property):
    def __init__(self, f):
        property.__init__(self, classmethod(f))

    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()


class MetaInformation(models.Model):
    ''' Class to hold meta information about any base class. Unique
        in the database for each base class '''
    last_global_update  = models.DateTimeField(default=dt.now)
    name                = models.CharField()

    @classmethod
    def get_last_global_update(self, base_class):
        return self.objects.get_or_create(name=base_class)[0].last_global_update

    @classmethod
    def update(self, base_class):
        s = self.objects.get_or_create(name=base_class)[0]
        s.last_global_update = dt.now()
        s.save()


class Site(models.Model):
    @classproperty
    def last_global_update(self):
        return MetaInformation.get_last_global_update('Site')

    @classmethod
    def update(self):
        MetaInformation.update('Site')
```